# Select input of form doesn't render on php email

Tags: php

I have a form that includes some select inputs like this

```
<select class="motive" name="motive">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Number</option>
    <option value="">One</option>
    <option value="">Two</option>
    <option value="">Three</option>
</select>
```

On my php form side I have this piece of code

```
$motive = $_POST['motive'];
```

In my received email I'm not getting the motive displayed, is showing as a blank space. Can someone tell me why?

thanks!

Comment: Disabled inputs are not passed to the server.

Comment: @dferenc disabled one is just to display as a placeholder, the other 3 ones are normal <options> and even if selected they doesn't render on mail :(

Comment: You will need to provide more details. How does that form get submitted to the php script? How do you construct your email? And what does the `$_POST` superglobal actually contain?

Comment: Solution was right in front of my eyes!! and yours:) simply added the same name of each option within the <option value=""> it was empty, that's why it wasn't rendering anything on the received email. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

For each of your `<option>` tags, you must have a `value` attribute set.

```
<select class="motive" name="motive">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Number</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="2">Three</option>
</select>
```

If user has option One selected and submits the form, then in PHP you

`$selected_motive = $_POST['motive']; // equals "1"`

Answer (score -1):

It's probably because `<select>` inputs are not allowed in emails. Most email clients will just remove them.

Comment: What? Could you please explain this a bit? It sounds... well... strange...

Comment: or there's a solution for it? @rockhopper72

Comment: Email clients only allow a subset of HTML and CSS (which varies between clients). For example, users would not want Javascript loading in email clients.

Comment: As a workaround, just link to your website in the email where the user can fill out the form there.

Comment: The OP is talking about an html form. Most likely the result of posting that form to a server side php script is the process that sends an email. It is not the select tag being part of the email.

Comment: We will need to wait until the OP provides more information about his setup. I do apologize if I were wrong and took back my vote. Sorry.

Comment: OK, so I was right, this answer leads into the complete wrong direction. This question is NOT about a select tag getting rendered inside an email message.

Comment: @Eugenio please add that additional information to the question as I asked in the comment to the question.

Comment: Is it because the value is empty in each option?